# Controlling Speed of a Single Phase 120v AC Motor

Tags: microcontroller, motor, ac

I have a drill press from the 1930s.  The motor has no markings and is likely from the 50s or later.  Right now, it is single phase 120v on/off.  I was wondering if it were possible to control the motor's speed using a micro-controller.  From what I am reading, the answer is no.

Please correct me if I am wrong, but PWM will not work, nor will varying the voltage. As well, there are potentially dangerous current issues if the frequency of the ac voltage is made too low.

Am I missing any possible solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would not say it is impossible. It is just more trouble than it is worth. The easiest thing would be to replace the original motor with a 3 phase motor. Then use a small AC drive to control the speed of the three phase motor. There are AC drives that operate from 120V single phase and can drive 240V 3 phase motors up to around 1 HP (0.75kW).

Comment: The motor is most likley a series-wound brushed one, so any triac speed controller would do the job.

Comment: Brushed motor on a drill press? Possible but unlikely. However it'll be obvious from looking at the motor.

Comment: Yeah, I think every drill press I have ever seen used an AC induction motor, even cheap ones.